# Normals of an implicit surface

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, computational-geometry

I have a function $f\colon\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$. For two numbers $a$ and $b$, I define the function $g$ by 
$$
g(\rho,\theta,\phi)=f\bigl(\rho\cos(a\theta)\sin(b\phi), \rho\sin(a\theta)\sin(b\phi), \rho\cos(b\phi)\bigr).
$$
With the help of a computer, I derive the implicit surface $g(\rho,\theta,\phi)=0$. I consider that the points of this surface are spherical coordinates, and I convert them to Cartesian coordinates: $(\rho,\theta,\phi) \mapsto (\rho\cos\theta\sin\phi, \rho\sin\theta\sin\phi, \rho\cos\phi)$. In this way I get a new surface. My problem is to get the normals of this surface. How to get the normals? I have the gradient of $f$.

Answer (score 0):

The normal to a surface $S\subset \Bbb R^3$ defined by $S=F^{-1}(\{0\})$ for a smooth function $F:\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R$ with $0$ as a regular value is just $\nabla F$. This means that at any point $p\in S$, the normal is $\nabla_p F$ (you can scale it if you want it to be unitary), and the tangent space $T_pS$ is just $\nabla_p F^\perp$.

Now you just have to compute $\nabla g(p)$ in terms of $\nabla f(p)$, $a$ and $b$. Note that $g$ is of the form $g=f\circ h$ with $h$ defined by 
$$h(\rho,\theta,\phi)=\bigl(\rho\cos(a\theta)\sin(b\phi), \rho\sin(a\theta)\sin(b\phi), \rho\cos(b\phi)\bigr).$$
Using the chain rule you have for all $u\in\Bbb R^3$
$$d_p g(u)=d_{h(p)}f\circ d_p h(u)= \langle \nabla f(h(p)), d_ph(u)\rangle.$$
Compute $d_ph(u)$, develop the scalar product and write it in the form 
$$a_1u_1+a_2u_2+a_3u_3$$
and you will have $\nabla g(p)=(a_1,a_2,a_3)$.

Comment: Thanks. I'm afraid my question is not clear. I don't want the normals of $\{g = 0\}$. After getting the surface $\{g = 0\}$, I transform it by converting to Cartesian coordinates. This gives a new surface, and I want the normals of this one. Is it clearer ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent ok so you have $S=\{g=0\}$ and you want to look at the normal of $T(S)$ where $T:(\rho,\theta,\phi) \mapsto (\rho\cos\theta\sin\phi, \rho\sin\theta\sin\phi, \rho\cos\phi)$?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I think that in general it is not true that "if $n$ is the normal of $S$ at $p\in S$, then $dT_p(n)$ is the normal of $T(S)$ at $T(p)$". This is true if $T$ is an isometry. But $dT_p:T_pS\to T_{T(p)}T(S)$ takes a basis to a basis, so (I think) you can take a basis of $T_pS$, take its image via $dT_p$ and compute the normal by using cross product.